# What is a non-blocking Rest Client?

Tags: rest, asynchronous, nonblocking, jersey-2.0

Have been through a lot of stuff explaining the fine line of difference between non-blocking and asynchronous I/O, but most seem to pertain to server side programming. And it seems to make sense as well. But could non-blocking vs. asynchronous I/O have a relevance in terms of a Rest Client?

Have spent a lot of time on the net but am afraid, am still unable to grasp the difference or rather the significance of having a non-blocking Rest Client. Am more concerned with Jersey Client. Yes, the API says that it supports Asynchronous Client and that a blocking "get" call on the Future object could be avoided using Future.isDone() (ref: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/async.html) but if my Rest Client makes a Post request how is that handled? Is it just asynchronous or is it asynchronous and non-blocking as well? Would be much grateful if anyone could help me with an insight.

Thanks and regards

Comment: Which underlying protocol do you use by REST? I don't think these terms count by HTTP, but I am not an expert of this topic. Can you elaborate your question?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend reading this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) from Microsoft on the topic.

The term "non-blocking" really means the same thing whether it is happening on the server side or the client side. As the article above points out, blocking means that the thread you make the call on stops processing until the call has finished. The Task async pattern described in the article makes it possible to await a Rest call instead of blocking the thread. Generally, if a method returns a Task, and the method is suffixed with async, it will be a non-blocking call. This means that it can be ran concurrently with other calls so that calls do not need to be ran in a sequence. They can be ran in parallel.

Here is an example where non-blocking rest calls are made in parallel and awaited so that they do not block each other. A simple for loop without the parallel would achieve the same result because it would kick the calls off in a sequence but would not block on each call.

```
var tasks = new List<Task<Response<Person>>>();

var client = clientFactory.CreateClient();

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    tasks.Add(client.GetAsync<Person>(new Uri("JsonPerson", UriKind.Relative)));
}

var results = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

[Full code](https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/RestClient.Net/blob/1deaa083f3f97ddd284478e2b19c71a844105fd8/RestClient.Net.UnitTests/UnitTests.cs#L1018)